# ASP.NET <%= %> vs <%: %>

Tags: asp.net, syntax, .net-4.0

It seems I am missing something.  But ever since .Net 4.0 came out I have been seeing reference to `<%: %>` syntax for ASP.NET.   It seems like it is similar to `<%= %>`  but clearly there is a reason for the new syntax. I tried google but searching `<%: %>` doesn't seem to return anything.  What does the `<%: %>` syntax do?  Was it introduced in .Net 4.0 or 3.5? Can someone enlighten me?

**Edited:**  Please provide reference or examples

Comment: It automatically Html encodes the output.  It's new in 4.  I'm sure you will get more information from someone in an answer though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i believe the <%: %> is auto HtmlEncoding

this post from Scott Gu will help to explain - it was introduced in .net 4 and MVC2

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Comment: This is correct, <%: %> is pretty much equivalent to doing <%= Html.Encode(...) %>

Comment: and what abou <%#: ?

Answer (score 4):

`:` does html encoding.

Scott Guthrie has [a nice post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) describing it in detail.

Don't use this where it is already encoded otherwise it will double encoded it. This is useful if you want to output things like HTML, though.