# Loading JS file using Url.Content in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, load

I am trying to load a javascript using the following in MVC 3, but the script does not load:

```
 <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content........
```

If I load using the following then it works:

```
<script src="../../Content......
```

What could be the problem

Answer (score 2):

When loading Scripts, I tend to use a custom helper instead.

The code below does this, and has an additional boolean parameter that can be used when the script is not local to your applicaiton, and on a CDN for instance.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, bool local = true)
    {
        if (local) {
            src = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Scripts/" + src);
        }
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("script");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", src);
        builder.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

    }
```

You can then call the helper in your view like this:

```
<%: Html.Script("jquery.validate.min.js") %>
```

or:

```
<%: Html.Script("http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.js", false) %>
```

Comment: I get the error Html does not contain definition for 'Script'

Comment: You need to include the namespace in the web.config where you created the Script method: 


`<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"> <namespaces> <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/> <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/> <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/> <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/> <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/> <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/> <add namespace="MyMVCHelperNamespace"/> </namespaces> </pages>`

Answer (score 1):

You should first Add an Assembly(namespace)

```
System.Web.Optimization
```

then simple render any Script like this.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/Scripts/test.js")
```

do not forget to include namespace first

```
Using System.Web.Optimization;
```

Comment: And fully refresh the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Note `<%:` renders an HTMLString and you do not want that.   `<%=` renders a string.
Below should work.

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content........
```

see this question for details [ASP.NET <%= %> vs <%: %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979255/asp-net-vs)

Comment: @RamaDesai  just look at the output of your <%: in the above code.  It will HTMLEncode the string.   Trust me for rendering URLs or URIs you should be using <%=

Comment: Even using <%= does not load the js file.

Comment: @Rama Desai You have some other issue then.  Are you receiving Console errors?  Is your HTML Valid?

Comment: Html is valid. When I use  <script src="../../Content every thing works fine.

Comment: If I type this in address bar: http://localhost:49639/Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js  I get nothing, yet the file exists in that folder

Comment: Can you answer the question, What does `<%= Url.Content("~/Content........` render?