# Mimic Razor syntax in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms

Here is an example from some MVC application on dynamic class generation for menu items coded as `<li>` elements. I guess this is Razor syntax. How can I implement same functionality within my legacy ASP.NET Web Forms (4.6) application?

```
<li class="@Html.SomeFunction(SomeArgument)">
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use razor with ASP.NET Web forms.

Comment: Use the syntax `<%= Html.SomeFunction(SomeArgument) %>` or `<%: Html.SomeFunction(SomeArgument) %>` depending on whether or not you want the output to be HTML encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Michael Liu answer I found this thread explaining things in more details [ASP.NET <%= %> vs <%: %>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979255/asp-net-vs)